# OpenCV: cascade training for a single object

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to train a cascade to detect the character '1' on a blank piece of paper. So far I've been using subsets of the 3019 background images from Naotoshi Seo's tutorial. Just wondering if anyone knows a good way to train something against a known background? opencv_traincascade doesn't seem to like me using one image as the negative sample. I'm only using one positive sample before running opencv_createsamples. How should I set the rotations during opencv_createsamples?

Also, just to clarify, I'm using LBP training rather than haartraining.

Comment: capture a lot of blank sheets of paper (or anything that could be on that paper sheet except your object). You should add different lighting conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Micka's comment is sensible in that a "known background" is never constant.
The best background negative images are realistic ones, eg texture constrasts, shadings, lighting in general, whatever will be the real background.